# Получить список уникальных значений

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить список всех значений username без повторений?

Comment: что есть "повторения"?

Comment: Список из всех username, чтобы имя не повторялось в списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM table
```

`table` название таблицы